# How can you know that your Facebook post has been shared/linked on a web-site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

For example, my Facebook post has been linked in a Quora question or a WordPress blog and also visited several times from there. Can I somehow learn about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to your page and click on "Insights" then click "Posts" on the left
then scroll down to "All Posts Published" and view the Engagement column

Answer (score 1):

If you click the down arrow in the top right corner of the post, one of the options is an embed link. This will give you a URL of the form, https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fuser.name%2Fposts%2F1234567890123. Presumably, anyone linking your post will need to use this link or one very similar. You might try searching Google for this link or even just the post number.